# Flutter prevent double submission of forms

Tags: flutter, dart

There is some way to prevent double submission of forms in flutter? I've had problems with it and I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use for the form?

Answer (score 0):

you can do either one of these:

1. disable the submit button
2. replace the button with the loader
3. show a modal loader